# SSIS looping through Files multiple times i

Tags: sql, ssis

I have an SSIS package where part of it loops through a directory and dumps every filename into a sql table.
Functionally, it works and I can use it.
I'm able to find what I need easy with a SELECT DISTINCT, but for performance purposes, I'd like to stop it from doing this.
However, the files in the directory are all excel files(not sure if that's relevant) and instead of getting all 50 files, I get duplicates of every filename.

Oddly enough, it saves every file name exactly 1024 times.

Anyone have any hints?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did it ever work correctly, or is this new behavior?

Comment: Newly created, has always done this.

Comment: This is a new one. Could you post a screenshot of the ForEach loop setting?  Does it do this across file types and directories?

Comment: Added pics, nothing special in the settings.  Such a weird thing to occur.  Particularly that it's exactly 1024 every time.

Comment: do you have multiple for loops nested inside each other?

Comment: No, just the one loop.

Comment: Do you use a stored proc to do the insert?  Does it have a JOIN to another table that could cause multiple inserts?

Comment: No, using a data flow inside the loop, and the destination is an OLE DB data source.  The table is alone, no joins.

Comment: What does your table look like that stores this data? Could you post the schema definition along with your insert mechanism (statement or proc) and however you're accessing the data? I suspect there's a logic issue somewhere

Comment: Well, managed to work around it.  Instead of using a data flow, I just used an insert query in an execute sql task and it worked fine.